# Matrices of some linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume that $T$ is linear transformation. Find the matrix of $T$.

a) $T:  R^2 $ → $ R^2 $ first rotates points through $ -\frac {3π}{4} $ radians (clockwise) and then reflects points through the horizontal $x_1$-axis.

b) $T:  R^2 $ → $ R^2 $ first reflects points through the horizontal $x_1$-axis and then reflects points through the line $x_1=x_2$. Show that this transformation is merely a rotation about the origin. What is the angle of the rotation?

I am unsure where to start with this since i am new with this, so could anyone explain to me how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: For linear transformations, the matrix of the composition is the product of the matrices

Answer (score 1):

I'll do a and let you tackle the second. A rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^2$ representing rotation by angle $\theta$ is given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta&-\sin \theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}
$$
reflection accross the $x$ axis is given by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\
0&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
so in your case we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\
0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos -\frac{3\pi}{4}&-\sin -\frac{3\pi}{4}\\
\sin-\frac{3\pi}{4}&\cos-\frac{3\pi}{4}\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\
0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}& -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{bmatrix}
$$
carrying out the matrix multiplication yields
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}& -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Is this clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation? (Since op mentions $-3\pi/4$ clockwise and I belive the rotation matrix you give is for counter-clockwise rotations).

Comment: @1524 nuts, I didn't catch that

Comment: One should stress the fact that it is the matrix of a symmetry (symmetry composed with rotation = symmetry).

Comment: Regarding the direction of rotation.  If you are in doubt, about how a matrix transforms your space, just look at what your matrix does to the principal component vectors $\pmatrix{1\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1}$